# Vue.js 3.0 - Update component UI when store property value changes via composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am writing a Vue.js app using Vue.js 3.0. I'm using this as a way to learn the composition API. One thing that is unclear to me is how to conditionally update my component UI when a store value is updated. To demonstrate my issue, I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uhmn9rg/1/). The code is detailed here:

**JavaScript**

```js
const store = {
  state: reactive({
    result = null
  }),
  generateNewValue() {
    this.state.result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
};

const MyApp = {
  setup() {
    return {
    }
  }
}
const myApp = Vue.createApp(MyApp)

myApp.component("banner", 
  { 
    template: '<button @click="onGenerateClick">generate</button>',
    setup(props) {
      console.log('setting up...');
    },
    methods: {
      onGenerateClick() {
        store.generateNewValue();
      }
    }
  }
);

myApp.component("content", {
  template: '<div><span>Content</span><button @click="onGenerateClick">generate</button></div>',
  methods: {
    onGenerateClick() {
      store.generateNewValue();
    }
  }  
});

myApp.mount('#my-vue')
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="my-vue">
  <banner></banner>
  <hr />
  <content></content>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.even-banner {
  background-color:navy;
  color: #fff;
}

.even-content {
  background-color:blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.odd-banner {
  background-color:maroon;
  color:#fff;
}

.odd-content {
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

When I click the "generate" button, a random number is generated. If that number is even, I want to set the `content` div to use the `even` CSS class. If it is an odd number, I want to apply the `odd` CSS class. I'm somewhat stuck though.

My problem is, I can successfully set the state value in the global store. However, I do not know how to react to property value changes in the components. I added a `watchEffect`, in my `setup` functions. However, that does not give me access to the state of the individual component itself. I'm trying to figure out a way in each component to say "hey, when this property in the store changes, update the UI like this.".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`computed()`](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#computed) prop to track the state's value (e.g., to test whether it's even):

```js
const MyApp = {
  setup() {
    return {
      isEven: computed(() => store.state.result % 2 === 0)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, use that prop in the template to apply a [conditional class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax):

```html
<content :class="{ 'even-content': isEven, 'odd-content': !isEven }">
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld/e5qvn03z/8/)